# How to get user videos directory?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I tried this:

```
userVideosDirectory = Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath
                                 (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).FullName + "\\Videos";
```

But that give me:

```
C:\Users\username\AppData\Videos
```

But I don't have the directory AppData there only:

```
C:\Users\username\Videos
```

How do I get the Videos directory without the AppData ?

Comment: `Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData`  gives you AppData folder path.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the videos folder using [`Environment.SpecialFolders.MyVideos` property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx), and get the actual path to it using the [`Environment.GetFolderPath` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getfolderpath).

```
string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);
```

Note that [that `enum`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder.aspx) contains many more folders you can get.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this?

```
string path = System.Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyVideos);
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like that:

```
int userVideosDirectory = (Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath
                                  (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).FullName + "\\Videos").IndexOf(@"\AppData\");

if (userVideosDirectory != 0)
{
    string str = (Directory.GetParent(Environment.GetFolderPath
                      (Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)).FullName + "\\Videos").Remove(userVideosDirectory, @"\AppData".Length);
}
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain please? My way is a little more tricky than Patrick's but it does what is meant to do.

Comment: I will. You can change the location of any special folder in Windows. That means you can't rely on combining paths, like your `ApplicationData` and `Videos`. It can be something totally different like `D:\myvids`.